# Keyboard always visible in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know if it's possible to have the native keyboard always visible. So I don't need to tap to have the text field in focus.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of Codename One at least on iOS & Android unless a fallback mode happened. This fallback mode happens when components can't be scrolled to e.g. if the text fields weren't in a box layout Y that's scrollable on a Y axis.

Comment: So how can I make the keyboard visible even when the text field in not in focus? Is it possible to see a code snippet?

Comment: You can use startEdit() on a text field but the keyboard will stay visible after you finish editing by default. This works the other way around, you should submit a code snippet that "doesn't work" because my options for code snippets at this point are nearly infinite...

Comment: tnx for the answer. The scenario is as soon as the screen with the search bar (text field) appears I want the keyboard to be visible and the text field in focus (without touching the text field). How do I open the keyboard programmatically? I tried StartEditing() doesn't work )...

Comment: How did you call startEdit? Make sure you called it after the transition completed you can bind a listener to transition completion.